# apt dist-upgrade wants to install firefox that is already installed by snap

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, firefox, snap

In Ubuntu 22.04 I have firefox 115.0.2 (the last version to date AFAIK) installed by default via snap (`which firefox` returns "/snap/bin/firefox").

Yet, when I try to use apt to do a dist-upgrade (`sudo apt dist-upgrade`) it wants to install firefox as a NEW package (not an upgrade).

I canceled the apt command as I don't understand why this behavior. Does anyone known why apt is proposing a new install ? Is it safe to proceed ?

Thank you for your help

ltdm

List of the outputs asked by Raffa (thanks to him), sorry it is auto translated from French, but should be easy to understand:

```
$ sudo apt update
     Reached:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
     Reached:2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
     Reached:3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
     Reached:4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
     Reading package lists... Done
     Building the dependency tree... Done
     Reading status information... Done
     35 packages can be updated. Run “apt list --upgradable” to see them.


$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

         Reading package lists... Done
     Building the dependency tree... Done
     Reading status information... Done
     Calculating the update... Done
     The following packages were installed automatically and are no longer needed:
       fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-extra
     Please use "sudo apt autoremove" to remove them.
     Get more security updates through Ubuntu Pro with 'esm-apps' enabled:
       libpostproc55 libavcodec58 libavutil56 libswscale5 libswresample3
       libavformat58 libavfilter7
     Learn more about Ubuntu Pro at https://ubuntu.com/pro
    
     An OpenSSL vulnerability has recently been fixed with USN-6188-1 & 6119-1:
     CVE-2023-2650: possible DoS translating ASN.1 object identifiers.
     Ensure you have updated the package to its latest version.
    
     The following NEW packages will be installed:
       firefox
     The following packages have been retained:
       gjs libgjs0g
     The following packages will be updated:
       alsa-ucm-conf gir1.2-adw-1 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-mutter-10 gnome-desktop3-data gnome-shell gnome-shell-common initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin initramfs-tools-core libadwaita-1-0
       libgnome-bg-4-1 libgnome-desktop-3-19 libgnome-desktop-4-1 libidn12 libinput-bin libinput10 libmm-glib0 libmutter-10-0 libspeechd2 modemmanager mutter-common python3-debian python3-speechd
       speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard
     33 updated, 1 newly installed, 0 to be removed and 2 not updated.
     It is necessary to take 9001 KB from the archives.
     After this operation, an additional 375 kB of disk space will be used.
     Would you like to continue ? [We]

$ apt list --installed firefox
     Listing... Done

$ snap list firefox
     Name Version Revision Tracking Editor Notes
     firefox 115.0.2-1 2908 latest/stable/… mozilla✓ -

$ apt show firefox
     Package: firefox
     Version: 1:1snap1-0ubuntu2
     Priority: optional
     Department: website
     Origin: Ubuntu
     Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
     Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
     Installed-Size: 261 kB
     Provides: gnome-www-browser, iceweasel, www-browser, x-www-browser
     Pre-Depends: debconf, snapd
     Depends: debconf (>= 0.5) | debconf-2.0
     Breaks: firefox-dbg (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-dev (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-geckodriver (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-mozsymbols (<< 1:1snap1)
     Replaces: firefox-dbg (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-dev (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-geckodriver (<< 1:1snap1), firefox-mozsymbols (<< 1:1snap1)
     Task: xubuntu-live, ubuntukylin-desktop
     Download-Size: 72.3 kB
     APT-Sources: http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
     Description: Transitional package - firefox -> firefox snap
      This is a transitional dummy package. It can safely be removed.
      .
      firefox is now replaced by the firefox snap.
```

Comment: Please show the **full** output of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade` by copying from the terminal and pasting to your question.

Comment: Please also add the output of `apt list --installed firefox` and `snap list firefox` ... Also `115.0.2` isn't yet available through snap on Ubuntu 22.04 AFAIK

Comment: Thank you for your comments

Comment: Here are the results (sorry it is in French but should be easy to understand):
sudo apt update
Atteint :1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease
Atteint :2 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Atteint :3 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Atteint :4 http://fr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances... Fait
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait      
35 paquets peuvent être mis à jour. Exécutez « apt list --upgradable » pour les voir.

Comment: Les NOUVEAUX paquets suivants seront installés :
  firefox
Les paquets suivants ont été conservés :
  gjs libgjs0g
Les paquets suivants seront mis à jour :
  (...)
  speech-dispatcher speech-dispatcher-audio-plugins speech-dispatcher-espeak-ng ubuntu-advantage-tools ubuntu-desktop ubuntu-desktop-minimal ubuntu-drivers-common ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard
33 mis à jour, 1 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 2 non mis à jour.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output ... Comments are not suitable for formatting it

Comment: apt list --installed firefox
En train de lister... Fait

snap list firefox
Nom      Version    Révision  Suivi            Éditeur   Notes
firefox  115.0.2-1  2908      latest/stable/…  mozilla✓  -

Comment: Sorry for that. I am new here. Thank you again. I wille edit the question.

Comment: Please add the output of `apt show firefox`

Comment: It's safe to install ... I will write an answer explaining that in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did refresh my FireFox snap installation and it turned out the latest version is indeed `115.0.2-1`.

Your `apt show firefox` output shows the normal expected package information:

```
Description: Transitional package - firefox -> firefox snap
      This is a transitional dummy package. It can safely be removed.
      .
      firefox is now replaced by the firefox snap.
```

That package can be removed which seems like what you did given the output of:

```
$ apt list --installed firefox
  Listing... Done
```

And it can be safely installed/reinstalled ... So, proceeding with your upgrade should not add a new copy of FireFox nor alter the currently installed one ... Although, I would use `upgrade` instead of `dist-upgrade` for that.

As for why APT is trying to install it, it's not clear to me given the information you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much for these quick and very comprehensive answers.
I'll have a look at the difference between dist-upgrade and upgrade.
Have a nice night or day (depending on where you are!).

Comment: @ltitodem You are welcome … And on this site you don’t need to mark a question as SOLVED … It’s enough to accept an answer which you did :-) … Have a nice night too